# Why does Emacs indent my Lisp LOOP construct weirdly?

Tags: indentation, slime, common-lisp

I'm using Emacs and SLIME to edit Lisp code.

By default, Emacs indents my Lisp LOOP constructs like this:

```
(loop for x across dna1 
   for y across dna2 
   count (not (eql x y)))
```

But I expect it to line up subsequent lines with the first parameter:

```
(loop for x across dna1 
      for y across dna2 
      count (not (eql x y)))
```

This still works fine for other functions:

```
(+ 1
   2
   3)
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? Is it because LOOP is a macro? Is there a way to fix it? Should I fix it?

Comment: Lisp mode has an indent function (you can see its value if you do `(symbol-plist 'loop)` and then look at the value of `lisp-indent-function` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use indentation provided by a SLIME contribution:

```
(require 'slime-cl-indent)
```

You may want to add that to the list `slime-contribs`- see [Loading Contribs](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Loading-Contribs.html) in the SLIME manual.

One can add it to the list of *SLIME contributions*:

```
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-cl-indent)
```

Comment: What worked for me was adding `(setq slime-contribs '(slime-cl-indent))` to `.emacs` as per the [SLIME github page](https://github.com/slime/slime#quick-setup-instructions).

Comment: I think the symbol to add to `slime-contribs` is not `slime-cl-indent` but `slime-indentation`. The slime source contains both a `slime-cl-indent` and a `slime-indentation`. The latter requires `slime-cl-indent` and contains a `define-slime-contrib` form with docstring "Contrib interfacing `slime-cl-indent` and SLIME."

Answer (score 3):

I found, it is more appropriate to add into contribs `'slime-indentation`. it will load `slime-cl-indent`.

And after that, you can use this code to choose required indentation style:

```
(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)
(setq common-lisp-style-default "sbcl")
```

Available styles are: `basic`, `classic`, `modern` and `sbcl`. All of them are defined in `slime-cl-indent.el` file, but you can define your own style as well.